# XNA animation switching position of two sprites

Tags: c#, arrays, xna, 2d, sprite

I'm creating a match-3 based game. The game is fully functional and the only things I yet need are animations. Now I would like to switch positions of two sprites, so I thought that what if I just would draw over what's behind then I wouldn't have to worry about switching anything as it would only happen visually.

```
public void Switch2(GameTime gameTime) 
{
    Vector2 sPos1 = new Vector2(16 + 50 * firstXint, 16 + 50 * firstYint);
    Vector2 sPos2 = new Vector2(16 + 50 * secondXint, 16 + 50 * secondYint);
    Vector2 a2 = new Vector2(16 + 50 * firstXint, 16 + 50 * firstYint);
    Vector2 b2 = new Vector2(16 + 50 * secondXint, 16 + 50 * secondYint);
    Vector2 ag2 = new Vector2(14 + 50 * firstXint, 14 + 50 * firstYint);
    Vector2 bg2 = new Vector2(14 + 50 * secondXint, 14 * secondYint);

    if (sPos1.X <= b2.X)
    {
        sPos1 = sPos1 + spriteSpeedX * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    }
    if (sPos2.X >= a2.X)
    {
        sPos2 = sPos2 - spriteSpeedX * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    }

    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.Draw(gridTexture, ag2, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.End();

    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.Draw(gridTexture, bg2, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.End();

    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.Draw(apple, sPos1, Color.WhiteSmoke);
    spriteBatch.End();

    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.Draw(strawberry, sPos2, Color.WhiteSmoke);
    spriteBatch.End();
}
```

This would work if I put the `Vector2`'s above this method, but then the `Vector2`'s could not use `firstXint` (place where the player clicks) etc. Then again if I try it this way the sprites won't move because the game would always call the method from the beginning thus `sPos1` and `sPos2` will never change. By the way the method is then called in the `Draw()` method.

Any ideas on how I could fix this? I can't come up with anything. (Maybe because I have been using XNA for 2 days, on beforehand the game was in a windows form application and instead of sprites there were only numbers)

Comment: I guess you have some kind of `Tile` class. Add a `TargetPosition` property to this class. When you switch two tiles, update the `TargetPosition`. In XNA's `Update` method update the actual position if it differs from the target. In XNA's `Draw` method use the actual position to draw the tile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, when you perform several `spriteBatch.Draw` you don't have to call `Begin` and `End` each time, this is very inefficient, you only need to do:

```
spriteBatch.Begin();
spriteBatch.Draw(gridTexture, ag2, Color.White);
spriteBatch.Draw(gridTexture, bg2, Color.White);
spriteBatch.Draw(apple, sPos1, Color.WhiteSmoke);
spriteBatch.Draw(strawberry, sPos2, Color.WhiteSmoke);
spriteBatch.End();
```

For your main problem, you wrote that you are calling this method in `Draw`, so this is called every game cycle, the main problem is that you initialize `sPos1` and `sPos2` and the update their values using `gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds`.

`gameTime.ElapsedGameTime` is fixed and counts the time between every cycle, and that's always about 16 milliseconds (if your game updates 60 times per second). This means that your sprites' positions never change.
You have to use `gameTime.TotalGameTime`, that keeps track of the time since the game was started, this should move your sprite.

Reference [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime_properties.aspx).